# Getting rows whose value are greater than the group mean

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a data frame where column "A" has 6 distinct values. Column "B" has float values. By using dplyr, I can group by column "A" and find mean of column "B" of each group as follows:

```
mydf %>% group_by(A) %>% summarize(Mean = mean(B, na.rm=TRUE))
```

My utter aim is to find rows in each group whose "B" values are higher than the group average. How can I achieve this (using base R or dplyr)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just `group` and then `filter`:

```
mydf %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  filter(B > mean(B, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple alternative with base R `ave` would be

```
df[df$b > ave(df$b, df$a) , ]

#   a  b
#4  1  4
#5  1  5
#9  2  9
#10 2 10
```

The default argument for `ave` is `mean` so no need to mention it explicitly, if there are `NA` values present in `b` modify it to

```
df[df$b > ave(df$b, df$a, FUN = function(x) mean(x,na.rm = TRUE)) , ]
```

---

Another solution with `subset` and `ave` as suggested by @Onyambu

```
subset(df,b>ave(b,a))

#   a  b
#4  1  4
#5  1  5
#9  2  9
#10 2 10
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = rep(c(1, 2), each = 5), b = 1:10)
df

#   a  b
#1  1  1
#2  1  2
#3  1  3
#4  1  4
#5  1  5
#6  2  6
#7  2  7
#8  2  8
#9  2  9
#10 2 10
```

Comment: since you are using the df parent.frame, you should use functions like `subset` ie: `subset(df,b>ave(b,a))` Although you still got my +1

Comment: @Onyambu nice! Do you mind if I update the answer with your suggestion ?

Answer (score 3):

Using Base R, I would go for this. It is not as elegant as dplyr.

```
mean.df <- aggregate(mydf$b, by =list(a = mydf$a), FUN = mean)
names(mean.df)[2] <- "mean"
mydf <- merge(mydf, mean.df, by = "a")
# Rows whose values are higher than mean
new.df <- subset(mydf, b > mean, select = -mean)
```

I like working with Data tables. So a `data.table` solution would be,

```
mydt <- data.table(mydf)
mydt[, mean := mean(b), by = a]
new.dt <- mydt[b > mean, -c("mean"), with = TRUE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it using base R and `tapply`:

```
mydf = cbind.data.frame(A=sample(6,20,rep=T),B=runif(20))
mydf.ave = tapply(mydf$B,mydf$A,mean)
newdf = mydf[mydf$B > mydf.ave[as.character(mydf$A)],]
```

(thus the one liner would be:`mydf[mydf$B > tapply(mydf$B,mydf$A,mean)[as.character(mydf$A)],]`)